# Stateful actors in Akka

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Let’s say I want to create a chat system with Akka.

In the system, I would probably have a UserActor that manages all messages for a certain user.

If I now deploy this in an Akka Cluster, how can I make sure that actorOf gets a (remote) reference to the right UserActor for a certain user? So no duplicates exists on different nodes...

Answer (score 5):

There is [Akka Cluster Sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html), which ensures that an actor with a certain Entity ID (like your User ID), exists only once, are balanced in the cluster, and could even be persisted to disk / storage.